# Checking if a nested object contains only single key-value pair in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, nested

I want to check if a deeply nested object consists of single key-value pair, if it does, it should return true else false.

For e.g., I want the below code to return `true`,

```
var test = {
              level1:
                {
                  level2:
                     {
                       level3:'level3'
                     }
                } 
            };
```

And the below code to return `false`,

```
var test2 = {
                level1: {
                  level2: {'a': '1', 'b': 2},
                  level3: {'a': '2', 'c': 4}
                }
            };
```

Also, the below code should return `true`,

```
var test3 = 
{
  level1: {
    level2: {
      level3: {
        level4: {
          1: "1",
          2: "2",
          3: "3",
          4: "4"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I made the following program for it, but it doesn't work,

```
function checkNested(obj) {
  if(typeof(obj) === 'object') {
    if(Object.keys(obj).length === 1) {
      var key = Object.keys(obj);
      checkNested(obj[key])
    } else { 
      return(false);
    }
  }
  return(true);
}
```

Could someone please suggest me how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `var key = Object.keys(obj);`, `key` becomes an *array* (containing the one key), so `obj[key]` doesn't make sense. You might destructure the `[key]` instead:

```
const [key] = Object.keys(obj);
return checkNested(obj[key])
```

(make sure to `return` the recursive call)

Or, even better, use `Object.values`, since you don't actually care about the keys:

```js
var test = {
  level1: {
    level2: {
      level3: 'level3'
    }
  }
};

var test2 = {
  level1: {
    level2: 'level2',
    level3: 'level3'
  }
};

function checkNested(obj) {
  if (typeof(obj) === 'object') {
    const values = Object.values(obj);
    if (values.length !== 1) {
      return false;
    }
    return checkNested(values[0]);
  }
  return true;
}

console.log(checkNested(test));
console.log(checkNested(test2));
```

Comment: Your code is returning false for the below code, 
var test3 = 
{
  level1: {
    level2: {
      level3: {
        level4: {
          1: "1",
          2: "2",
          3: "3",
          4: "4"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: Yep, because it has more than one nested key-value pair.

Comment: Hi, I updated my question, I want the code to return true even for test3

Comment: It *does* return false for `test3`. (as your first comment noted)

Comment: My bad, I want it to return true even in such cases as test3

Comment: Why? There is more than one nested key-value pair. Why does test3 pass, while test2 fails?

Comment: I updated the post, I want those 3 cases to be passed. I modified test2 a bit

Comment: But your question says you want ``And the below code (test2) to return false``. Do you actually want it to return `true`, so all three cases return `true`? (then why not `checkNested = () => true`? :P )

Comment: Hi, I updated my ques, test1->true, test2->false, test3->true

Comment: Ok, but **why** do you want `test2` to be `false`, while `test3` to be `true`? They both have multiple nested key-value pairs.